# C# Mongo Driver: Getting Time out, Connection refused by the server (Strange behavior)

Tags: c#, mongodb, timeout, mongodb-.net-driver, connection-refused

I was working with Mongo DB 3.4.2, and I am facing an strange issue when accessing data from my API. The error message says:

```
"ClassName": "System.TimeoutException",
    "Message": "A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server usingCompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", ConnectionMode : \"Automatic\", Type : \"Standalone\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"ServerIp:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"ServerIp:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

As you can see the issue says: **"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"** and we have already verified the following:

- There is no block port on the server.
- The firewall is not blocking
  the port.
- There is no proxy involve in the process

**The issue is solved by restarting the Mongo Db Service on the server, however the same issue comes up every 1 hour after restarting the service.**

Could somebody please help me with this,

Thanks

Comment: I doubt I can help you, but it might help others help you: can you post the server logs from around the time the error occurred?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your Mongo logs.

Comment: Were you able to fix the recurrence of the issue every one hour?